# JSON contains Special Characters

Tags: coldfusion, fullcalendar, coldfusion-9

My JSON contains special characters like: new line, double quotes etc.

I am creating the JSON using Coldfusion server side script. But in case of special chars I get error due to wrongly formatted JSON. What should I do in such a case?

```
<cfoutput>
[
    <cfset loopIndex=0>
    <cfloop query="qEvents">

        <cfif loopIndex NEQ 0>,</cfif>

        <cfif is_allday EQ 1>
            <cfset isallDayEvent = "true">
        <cfelse>
            <cfset isallDayEvent = "false">
        </cfif>

        {
            "title": "#title#",
            "start": "#DateFormat(start_date_time,'mm/dd/yyyy')# #TimeFormat(start_date_time,'hh:mm tt')#",
            "end": "#DateFormat(end_date_time,'mm/dd/yyyy')# #TimeFormat(end_date_time,'hh:mm tt')#",
            "allDay": #isallDayEvent#,
            "eventID": "#event_id#",
            "duration": "#duration#",
            "note": "#note#",
            "location": "#location#"
        }
        <cfset loopIndex=loopIndex+1>
    </cfloop>
]
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Are you using the "serailizeJSON()" function? Or are you relying on the returnformat of a CFC? How is the JSON generated Adil?

Comment: @All above
Thanks for your response. I have edited the post and have added the code. I know I am doing some blunder. Please let me know what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than writing the JSON by hand, you should generate an array of structs and then use `serializeJSON()` to convert it to a valid JSON string:

```
<cfset thisArrayBecomesJSON = [] />

<cfloop query="qEvents">

    <cfif is_allday EQ 1>
        <cfset isAllDayEvent = "true" />
    <cfelse>
        <cfset isAllDayEvent = "false" />
    </cfif>

    <cfset thisEvent = {
        'title' = title,
        'start' = dateFormat( start_date_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) & timeFormat( start_date_time, 'hh:mm tt' ),
        'end' = dateFormat( end_date_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) & timeFormat( end_date_time, 'hh:mm tt' ),
        'allDay' = isAllDayEvent,
        'eventID' = event_id,
        'duration' = duration,
        'note' = note,
        'location' = location
    } />

    <cfset arrayAppend( thisArrayBecomesJSON, thisEvent ) />

</cfloop>

<cfset myJSON = serializeJSON( thisArrayBecomesJSON ) />

<cfoutput>#myJSON#</cfoutput>
```

This is untested, but I think it should work ok - there may be some syntax errors.

Comment: There was no syntax error. But now I cannot validate the JSON.

Comment: What are you using to validate the JSON? Can you post an example of a JSON string being generated?

Comment: I am using the following two URLs to validate my JSON:
http://jsonlint.com/
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

The project is on my local machine and the JSON is very big. Almost 1000 records. Won't be able to share it here.

Comment: Well, without seeing the JSON being generated, it's kind of difficult to troubleshoot. Can you modify `qEvents` to only pull two or three events and then share the JSON for that smaller recordset?

Comment: The validater is not validating but the plugin is not giving any error.
The only problem now is that the plugin expects the values in deSerialized form.
e.g. Now my dates look like this: 01\/18\/2012 12:00
While the plugin expects date like this: 01/18/2012 12:00 

How Can i de-serialize the string in Javascript?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can parse the JSON string using `jQuery.parseJSON( jsonString )`. If not, you can use `JSON.parse( jsonString )`, but I'm not sure that it is cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Date in JSON is not well defined.  So you might need to format your Date to whatever the consumer expects it to be.

Comment: Thanks for great help
I am accepting your response as correct answer